# How does Google map know my direction as I rotate?

Tags: google-maps

I realize the blue arrow on Google map, as you rotate the phone around, it will rotate as well. May I know how does it know the north south direction? It works too even my GPS is turned off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GPS doesn't understand static direction at all; it can only infer direction from motion.  But there is an electronic compass inside the phone as well as the GPS.

You might want to download the "[GPS Status + Tools](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en)" program from the Market; you can see detailed status information for both the GPS and the compass.

Comment: To add...there's a magnetometer within almost all Android phones. This also allows your device to act like a metal detector. Quite a few apps in the market that enhance this functionality.